# testing django web app that uses cookies/session

Tags: django, unit-testing, session, testing, cookies

In views.py:

> `get_dict = Site.objects.getDictionary(request.COOKIES['siteid'])`

{gets a dictionary with site information based on id from cookie}
In tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
class WebAppTest(TestCase):
    def test_status(self):
        response = self.client.get('/main/',{})
        response.status_code # --->passed with code 200
        response = self.client.get('/webpage/',{'blog':1})
        response.status_code # ----> this is failing
```

In order to present blog page it goes to a view where it gets a dictionary using existing cookie, process it, renders templates, which works fine when running the app. But the tests are failing.Having never tested Django webapps I'm not sure how to test it right. Here is the traceback.
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/test/client.py", line 313, in post
    response = self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/django/data/../webpage/views.py", line 237, in getCostInfo
    get_dict = Site.objects.getDictionary(request.COOKIES['siteid'])
KeyError: 'siteid'
```

Went through some online samples but couldn't find something that deals in depth with cookies/sessions. Any ideas or directs to useful links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Persistent State](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#persistent-state) section of the [Django Testing docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/).

In your case, I would expect your test to be something more like:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
class WebAppTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        session = self.client.session
        session['siteid'] = 69 ## Or any valid siteid.
        session.save()
    def test_status(self):
        response = self.client.get('/main/',{})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)   
        response = self.client.get('/webpage/',{'blog':1})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: ah session.save() gave this AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'. commenting that part did work.this should be a good start.Could you please enlighten me why it did work when siteid stored in session. Thanks Jack.

Comment: Because there was no `siteid` in the session.

Comment: i also have store user's choice in request.session['choice'] in my views. Its complaining again,so i did try to update the client.session in the test like session.update({'choice':'technology'}). this is not working.It gives me key error 'choice'.Any idea? Sorry if this is not apt place to post it.

Comment: You probably need to learn more about dictionaries in Python if you don't understand this.  A key error is saying that the key 'choice' does not exist in the dictionary.  Which means you need to set it up first.

Comment: just found this probably that what was happening to me when i was trying to session.save () http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11475

Comment: The link is now broken.